# Break a CSS file into an array with PHP

Tags: php, css, regex, parsing

I wanted to break a css file into an array with PHP.

Ex:

```
#selector{ display:block; width:100px; }
#selector a{ float:left; text-decoration:none; }
```

Into a php array...

```
array(2) {
  ["#selector"] => array(2) {
    [0] => array(1) {
      ["display"] => string(5) "block"
    }
    [1] => array(1) {
      ["width"] => string(5) "100px"
    }
  }
  ["#selector a"] => array(2) {
    [0] => array(1) {
      ["float"] => string(4) "left"
    }
    [1] => array(1) {
      ["text-decoration"] => string(4) "none"
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Oh : Edit : I am not worried about ill formed CSS files in this instance. Doesn't ahve to be bulletproof as long as its not greedy

Comment: Oops I wrote something that did it the other way around.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<?php

$css = <<<CSS
#selector { display:block; width:100px; }
#selector a { float:left; text-decoration:none }
CSS;

//
function BreakCSS($css)
{

    $results = array();

    preg_match_all('/(.+?)\s?\{\s?(.+?)\s?\}/', $css, $matches);
    foreach($matches[0] AS $i=>$original)
        foreach(explode(';', $matches[2][$i]) AS $attr)
            if (strlen(trim($attr)) > 0) // for missing semicolon on last element, which is legal
            {
                list($name, $value) = explode(':', $attr);
                $results[$matches[1][$i]][trim($name)] = trim($value);
            }
    return $results;
}
var_dump(BreakCSS($css));
```

Quick Explanation: The regexp is simple and boring. It just matches all "anything, possible space, curly bracket, possible space, anything, close curly bracket". From there, the first match is the selector, the second match is the attribute list. Split that by semicolons, and you're left with key/value pairs. Some trim()'s in there to get rid of whitespace, and that's about it.

I'm guessing that your next best bet would probably be to explode the selector by a comma so that you can consolidate attributes that apply to the same thing etc., but I'll save that for you. :)

Edit: As mentioned above, a real grammar parser would be more practical... but if you're assuming well-formed CSS, there's no reason why you need to do anything beyond the simplest of "anything { anything }". Depends on what you want to do with it, really.

Comment: ..`sexplode()` eh? I did a double-take and checked the manual :P

Comment: I've translated this to Python during a process of migration in one of my projects, if you're interested, [check it out](https://gist.github.com/pooh110andco/5177066).

Comment: Fails on commented rules :-(

Answer (score 6):

If you need the same for CSS rules with multi selectors and with breaklines:

```
<?php                      
$css = "
#selector
{ display:block; 
width:100px; 
}
#selector a:hover div.asd, #asd h1.asd { 
float:left; 
text-decoration:none; 
}
";
preg_match_all( '/(?ims)([a-z0-9\s\,\.\:#_\-@]+)\{([^\}]*)\}/', $css, $arr);

$result = array();
foreach ($arr[0] as $i => $x)
{
    $selector = trim($arr[1][$i]);
    $rules = explode(';', trim($arr[2][$i]));
    $result[$selector] = array();
    foreach ($rules as $strRule)
    {
        if (!empty($strRule))
        {
            $rule = explode(":", $strRule);
            $result[$selector][][trim($rule[0])] = trim($rule[1]);
        }
    }
}   

var_dump($result);
?>
```

output:

```
array(2) {
  ["#selector"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["display"]=>
      string(5) "block"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["width"]=>
      string(5) "100px"
    }
  }
  ["#selector a:hover div.asd, #asd h1.asd"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["float"]=>
      string(4) "left"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["text-decoration"]=>
      string(4) "none"
    }
  }
}
```

**Update: Added support for multiple selectors like: .box, .element, div{ ... }**

Comment: Does not work correctly if selector is multiple: .box, .element, div{ ... }

Comment: Good, but doesn't work with `background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,........` type of values..

Comment: Does this work with @media of bootstrap. I tried using it, but it certainly ignores.

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I would build (or find) a real grammar for CSS, and do parsing that way. Trying to write a parser for any non-trivial expression language (and CSS clearly isn't trivial, with all the fancy selectors) have gotten me into trouble more than enough times.

Example: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1289-PHP-CSS-parser-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the selector `(?ims)([a-z0-9\s\,\.\:#_\-@*()\[\]"=]+)\{([^\}]*)\}` in the [answer of inakiabt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1215394/2933754) for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I will add also my solution. I had to split one large css file with all media queries into the separated files, so the mobile rating on the pagespeed rised for 10 points, because it doesn't need to wait for the whole large css file.

The output is an array splitted on media queries.

```
$path = 'my-css-file.css'
$css = file_get_contents($path);
$cleanCss = [];

// Remove css comments
$clean1 = explode('/*', $css);
foreach($clean1 as $clean2) {
    $clean3 = explode('*/', $clean2);
    $cleanCss[] = $clean3[count($clean3) -1];
}
$css = implode('', $cleanCss);
$temp = explode('}', $css);
$params = [];
$type = 'all';
$nextBracketIsNotMediaEnd = false;
foreach($temp as $tem2) {
    $data = explode('{', $tem2);
    if (count($data) == 1) {
        if ($nextBracketIsNotMediaEnd) {
            $nextBracketIsNotMediaEnd = false;
        } else {
            $type = 'all';
            continue;
        }
    }
    if (count($data) == 3) {
        $typeTemp = trim($data[0]);
        if (substr( $typeTemp, 0, 6 ) === "@media" ) {
            $type = $typeTemp;
            array_shift($data);
        } else {
            $data[1] = $data[0].$data[1];
            $nextBracketIsNotMediaEnd = true;
        }
    }
    if (count($data) == 2) {
        $rows = explode(';',$data[1]);

        $tempData = [];
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $paramsinline = explode(':', $row);
            if (empty($paramsinline[0]) || empty($paramsinline[1])){
                continue;
            }
            $tempData[trim($paramsinline[0])] = trim($paramsinline[1]);
        }
        $selector = trim($data[0]);
        if (!empty($tempData)) {
            if (empty($params[$type][$selector])) {
                $params[$type][$selector] = $tempData;
            } else {
                $params[$type][$selector] = array_merge($params[$type][$selector], $tempData);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Here you have the output, splitted by media queries
print_r($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that works with multiple font-face attributes and does not break on URLs so far:

```
function css_to_array( $css ): array {

    $results = array();

    preg_match_all('/@font-face\s?\{(.*?)\}\s?/s', $css, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[0] as $i => $original) {
        foreach (explode(';', $matches[1][$i]) as $attr) {
            if (strlen(trim($attr)) > 0) {
                list($name, $value) = explode(':', $attr, 2); // Limit the explode to only split on the first colon
                $results["@font-face"][$i][trim($name)] = trim($value);
            }
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```