# How do I get all height values from a string with php?

Tags: php

Users can enter text for a piece of content using WYSIWYG which is placed into the variable $body.  This may include multiple instances of `style="[maybe stuff] height:xpx [maybe stuff]"` or `height="xpx"`.

I need to get all of the height values that exist (the numbers only) so that I can add them together.

Note there may be other integer values within the string so it can't just grab all integers.

If the solution uses regex, I have never been able to understand it and I understand there are security issues with regex, so ideally I'm looking for a safe solution!

I'm certain this must be quite simple but I'm struggling!

Comment: There is nothing fundamentally wrong with using regular expressions for this. See e.g [Parse a CSS file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3618381)

Comment: what you have tried ? Post some code !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick, if I'm not mistaken:

```
preg_match_all('/height(\:|\=)"*\s*([0-9]+[^;"]+);*/i','<tr style="height: 123px; border: none;><tr height="125px"',$matches);
var_dump($matches[2]);//array('123px','125px');
```

But since you're going to let this regex loose on HTML (if I'm not mistaken), I'd look [at ways to *parse* the DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and use the [DOMElement's](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) methods to get what I want. It's a far more robust take on the problem.

As requested by OP:

```
function getDeepChildren($node,&$nodeArray)
{//recursive function to flatten dom
    $current = $node->getElementsByTagName('*');//get all children
    foreach($current as $node)
    {//loop through children
        $nodeArray[] = $node;//add child
        if ($node->hasChildNodes())
        {//if child node has children of its own
            getDeepChildren($node,$nodeArray);//get the children and append to nodeArray
        }
    }
}//no return value, $nodeArray is passed by reference
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($body);
$nodes = array();
getDeepChildren($dom,$nodes);//$nodes is passed by reference
$height = array();
while($node = array_shift($nodes))
{//$height[i][0] === height value, $height[i][1] is reference to node
    if ($node->hasAttribute('height'))
    {
        $height[] = array($node->getAttribute('height'),$node);
        continue;//already got what we need, no need for slow preg_match
        //in case of <div height="123px" style="border:1px solid #F00;"> for example...
    }
    if ($node->hasAttribute('style') && preg_match('/height\s*\:\s*([0-9]+\s*[a-z]+)\s*;/i',$node->getAttribute('style'),$match))
    {
        $height[] = array($match[1],$node);
    }
}
var_dump($height);//should contain everything you're looking for
```

For a more OO approach, I suggest looking at a couple of [recursive domnode iterator classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php).
Passing arrays by reference is discouraged, but it's the easiest way to get what you need here. An alternative version would be:

```
function getDeepChildren($node)
{
    $nodes = array();
    $current = $node->getElementsByTagName('*');
    foreach($current as $node)
    {
        $nodes[] = $node;
        if ($node->hasChildNodes())
        {
            $nodes = array_merge($nodes,getDeepChildren($node));
        }
    }
    return $nodes;
}
//instead of getDeepChildren($dom,$nodes), usage is:
$nodes = getDeepChildren($dom);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!  Elias Van Ootegem - your regex worked perfectly, however I decided to take your advise on parsing the DOM.  Answered below.

Comment: @user1173640: just a tip, instead of your snippet, traverse the elements and use `hasAttribute('height')` and `hasAttribute('style')`. In the case of a `height` attribute: `$node->getAttribute('height')` will give you what you need, else: `preg_match('/height\s*\:\s*([0-9]+[a-z])\s*;/i',$node->getAttribute('style'),$match)` will do the trick

Comment: Thanks Elias, would this fix HamZa's comment re possible spaces that might exist?  This is actually the first time I've ever parsed a dom like this (I'm getting there!) and I can't quite work out how to traverse the elements as you suggest.  I'd be extremely grateful if you could type that out within my code below.  Thanks again!

Comment: @user1173640: Updated my answer, That's the way I'd do things. And to address your concerns: yes, white-space in the style attribute of a tag is taken into consideration. Since JS has a pretty similar regex engine: `'foo style="bar:123; height  : 123px ; width:125;"'.match(/height\s*\:\s*([0-9]+\s*[a-z]+)\s*;/i);` and `'foo style="bar:123; height:123px ; width:125;"'.match(/height\s*\:\s*([0-9]+\s*[a-z]+)\s*;/i);` both produce the exact same result, just try it in your console

Comment: Thanks again Elias!  I really appreciate it.  Unfortunately no matter how much I've fiddled, searched, tweaked etc I've hit a brick wall.  I've mostly been getting - Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getDeepChildren() (previously declared in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/malt/sites/all/themes/maltblocks/templates/inject-content.tpl.php:29) in/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/malt/sites/all/themes/maltblocks/templates/inject-content.tpl.php on line 29.  In the end I've decided to add in a hacky work around, which seeing as the use case is low anyway (and will be me doing it) shld be ok.

Comment: If you get that `redeclare` error that either means you're working in an OO context, and accessing the same method several times, each time attempting to redeclare the function, or you're using recursive calls _or_ you're including the `getDeepChildren` function definition multiple times. Setup a pastebin and I might be able to fix this problem for you

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for your help!  Elias Van Ootegem - your regex worked perfectly, however I decided to take your advise on parsing the DOM.  This is the solution I found this way -

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($body);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

  $tags = $xpath->query('//div/@style');
$height = 'height:';
$totalheight = 0;
foreach ($tags as $tag) {

$str = trim($tag->nodeValue);
$height_str = strstr( $str, $height);
$totalheight = $totalheight + trim( substr( $height_str, strlen( $height), stripos(        $height_str, 'px;') - strlen( $height)));

}
```

Comment: What if the user types in "height : Xpx" (with spaces)? Exptect the unexpected !

Comment: Ok, commenting here might seem stalker-ish, but anyway: +1 for taking the time and effort to look into the parser-option. Since you've never done this, and nobody posted this link here, if you want to know _why_ you shouldn't use regex for this, and become a missionary for the enlightened elite who refuse to give in to _"the dark side"_, [this is a ravishing read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with regex, but maybe this will work?

```
<?php

$message = 'Hello world <p style="height: 80 px;width:20px">Some example</p><br />Second: DERP DERP <p style="color:#000;height:30 px;padding:10px;"> DERP</p>';
preg_match_all('#height\s?:\s?[0-9]+\s?px#', $message, $results);
$heights = str_replace(array('height', ':', ' ', 'px'), '', $results[0]);
echo array_sum($heights);

?>
```