# PHP to search a css file for a style

Tags: php, css, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse a CSS file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618381/parse-a-css-file-with-php)

I want to be able to search through a css file find the class or id and bring back its style.

IE.. css file layout

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0; 
}
span {
margin:0;
padding:0; 
} #input { font:12px arial; }
a { color:#0000FF;
text-decoration:none; 
}
.logout a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
```

and i want to find say the id " #input " in the file and it to bring back the style so.

```
font:12px arial;
```

or
    #input{ font:12px arial; }

and ovioulsly if there is more bring that back to but to keep this small like.

i tried my self but no luck as im not so good in regular expressions.

```
if(file_exists("css/style.css") && filesize("css/style.css") > 0){
$filesize = filesize("css/style.css");
$handle = fopen("css/style.css", "r");
$contents = fread($handle, $filesize);
fclose($handle);
}
preg_match('@^(?:#input{)?([^}]+)@i', $contents, $matches);
echo "style: {$matches[0]} <br>";
print_r($matches2);
```

please help.

Comment: it just brings back this body {
margin:0;
padding:0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific regex fails for a couple of reasons:

```
 @^(?:#input{)?([^}]+)@i
```

- The `^` marker means start of subject. Since your `#input {` CSS selector is not at the start of the regex, this would always fail.
- Secondly you are marking it optional with `(...)?`. So the regex will ignore looking for `#input` anyway.
- Then you also don't have the `{` escaped.
- And your actual CSS contains a space between `#input` and `{` which your regex does not account for.

More correct would be:

```
@(?:#input\s*\{)([^}]+)@i
```

See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: Thank you mario i quest that whats was happening but was not sure on how to get it to work. but thanks it works a treat

Comment: ok so how would i then go about finding say height and changing the value of the height so if the code is 
    height: 20px;
i want to change the 20px into 10px say so it would be 
    height: 10px;
but teh value will be different based on the search and the change value will be different also based on some other stuff.

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback` for finding the `{...}` block, then a second regex `height:\s*\d+px` with just `preg_replace` for the width and height.