# php regex to get strings that start with any character and end with open brace

Tags: php, regex

I have css file that I am trying to manipulate using php. So if my css is like...

```
.something {
    display:none;
    background: blue;
}

.somethingElse {
    display:block;
}
```

I want to be able to get an array of the class names. So my array would look like...

```
['.something', '.somethingElse']
```

This is my attempt (`$homepage` is my css file)...

```
$homepage = file_get_contents("style.css");
$regex = '/[\s\S]\K[^{]*(?=})/m';
preg_match_all($regex, $homepage, $matches);
```

What I tried to do was find all strings that start with any character and end in open brace `{`. My regex is all wrong, what is the proper way?

Comment: Try `'~^\h*\.([^\n{]*?)\s*{~m'`. To parse arbitrary CSS, use a CSS parser. See [Parse a CSS file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618381/parse-a-css-file-with-php).

Comment: I think you'd be better served with a CSS parser written in PHP.

Comment: What about multiple class names for one single CSS block? What if id names or other different selectors are between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work great:

```
\.([\w]+)\s*{
```

The class name is in group #1.

Example:

```
preg_match_all("/\.([\w]+)\s*{/", $homepage, $matches);
```