# Add element to every css rule in extracted style sheet (in string)

Tags: php, css, html-email, styling

I want to change every css rule in a string whitch I extracted from a HTML email body.
The string contains css inside a  element whitch influence my website styling.

I want to add an element (div class) to every css rule inside that string.
Is this possible with php?

Example:

```
$string = '<style type="text/css">body { blah blah } .div1 { blah blah } .div2 { blah blah }</style> Blah blah blah body text blah blah';

$extractcss = strip_tags($string , '<style>');
```

I want to add .mydiv to every css rule to get this:

```
$extractcss = '.mydiv body { blah blah } .mydiv .div1 { blah blah } .mydiv .div2 { blah blah }';
```

With the new string I want to influence the styling of the email body so that it no longer has any effect on my website styling.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could search for "PHP CSS Parser", there is sure to be a library out there that can accomplish this. Note that `.mydiv body` will not work.

Comment: Thansk for your comment. I didn't know how to search for an answere. Thanks to you I know I had to look for a PHP CSS Parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With te help of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618381/parse-a-css-file-with-php) I have the solution for my problem.

With the following function I parse the CSS from a string. After that I make a new css string with a div class in front of every css rule.

```
function parse_css($cssstring){
                            preg_match_all( '/(?ims)([a-z0-9\s\.\:#_\-@,]+)\{([^\}]*)\}/', $cssstring, $arr);
                            $result = array();
                            foreach ($arr[0] as $i => $x){
                                $selector = trim($arr[1][$i]);
                                $rules = explode(';', trim($arr[2][$i]));
                                $rules_arr = array();
                                foreach ($rules as $strRule){
                                    if (!empty($strRule)){
                                        $rule = explode(":", $strRule);
                                        $rules_arr[trim($rule[0])] = trim($rule[1]);
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                $selectors = explode(',', trim($selector));
                                foreach ($selectors as $strSel){
                                    $result[$strSel] = $rules_arr;
                                }
                            }
                            return $result;
                        }

// Extract and change css style
                        if ( str_contains($message, '<style') ) { 
                        
                            $extractcss = strip_tags($message, '<style>');
                            $parsecss = parse_css($extractcss);
                            $newcssstring = '<style type="text/css">';
                        
                            foreach ( $parsecss as $key => $value ) {
                                $newcssstring .= '.message-body '. $key .' { ';
                                    
                                    foreach ( $value as $k => $v ) {
                                        $newcssstring .= $k .': '. $v .'; ';
                                    }

                                $newcssstring .= ' } ';
                            }
                            $newcssstring .= '</style>';

                            $message = preg_replace("#([<]style)(.*)([<]/style[>])#s", "<!-- style extracted -->", $message);

                            $message= $newcssstring . $message;

                        }
```

**EDIT**

I searched for another css parse function. This one parses also media query's. I also changed this function so that selectors with , in it will be seperated.

```
function parse_css($css) {
    
    $cleanCss = [];

    // Remove css comments
    $clean1 = explode('/*', $css);
    foreach($clean1 as $clean2) {
        $clean3 = explode('*/', $clean2);
        $cleanCss[] = $clean3[count($clean3) -1];
    }
    $css = implode('', $cleanCss);

    // Make array of all css selectors
    $temp = explode('}', $css);
    $params = [];
    $type = 'all';
    $nextBracketIsNotMediaEnd = false;

    // Loop through all css selectors
    foreach( $temp as $tem2 ) {

        // Make array of all css rules
        $data = explode('{', $tem2);

        // 1 result in array probably end of media query
        if (count($data) == 1) {
            if ($nextBracketIsNotMediaEnd) {
                $nextBracketIsNotMediaEnd = false;
            } else {
                $type = 'all';
                continue;
            }
        }

        // 3 results in array probably begin media query with first rule
        if (count($data) == 3) {
            $typeTemp = trim($data[0]);
            if ( substr( $typeTemp, 0, 6 ) === "@media" ) {
                $type = $typeTemp;
                array_shift($data); // Delete media from array
            } else {
                $data[1] = $data[0].$data[1];
                $nextBracketIsNotMediaEnd = true;
            }
        }

        // 2 results in array probably one css rule
        if (count($data) == 2) {
            $rows = explode(';',$data[1]);
            
            $tempData = [];

            foreach($rows as $row) {
                $paramsinline = explode(':', $row);
                if (empty($paramsinline[0]) || empty($paramsinline[1])){
                    continue;
                }
                $tempData[trim($paramsinline[0])] = trim($paramsinline[1]);
            }

            $selector = trim($data[0]);

            // Make value for selector as $value when it's not excist
            if (!empty($tempData)) {
                if (empty($params[$type][$selector])) {
                    $value = $tempData;
                } else {
                    $value = array_merge($params[$type][$selector], $tempData);
                }
            } else {
                $value = '';
            }

            if ( $value != '' ) {

                // Split css selector with , in multiple selectors with same css rules
                if ( strpos($selector, ',') ) {
                    $selectors = explode(',', $selector);
                    foreach ($selectors as $newselector){
                        $params[$type][$newselector] = $value;
                    }
                } else {
                    $params[$type][$selector] = $value;
                }

            }
            
        }
    }
    return $params;
}
```

The code that put the class message-body in front of every selector is changed to:

```
$message = 'message (email) body'; 
   
if ( str_contains($message, 'style') ) { 
                            
                            // Strip all tags except for <style> tags and change the <style> tags to STARTSTYLE and ENDSTYLE
                            $extractcss = strip_tags($message, '<style>');
                            $extractcss = str_replace('<style type="text/css">', 'STARTSTYLE', $extractcss);
                            $extractcss = str_replace('</style>', 'ENDSTYLE', $extractcss); 

                            // Get every css between STARTSTYLE and ENDSTYLE
                            preg_match_all( '/STARTSTYLE(.*?)ENDSTYLE/s', $extractcss, $arr);

                            $newcssstring = '';

                            // Loop through all css between every <style> tag and put .message-body in fornt of every css selector
                            foreach ( $arr[1] as $css ) {

                                $parsecss = parse_css($css);

                                //echo '<pre>'. print_r($parsecss, true) .'</pre>';

                                $newcssstring .= '<style type="text/css">';
                            
                                foreach ( $parsecss as $parsedelement => $valuee ) {

                                    $mediaquery = false;
                                    
                                    if ( strpos($parsedelement, 'media') ) {
                                        $newcssstring .= $parsedelement .' { ';
                                        $mediaquery = true;
                                    }
                                
                                foreach ( $valuee as $element => $value ) {
                                    
                                    $newcssstring .= '.message-body '. $element .' { ';
                                
                                    foreach ( $value as $k => $v ) {
                                    $newcssstring .= $k .': '. $v .'; ';
                                    }
                                
                                    $newcssstring .= ' } ';
                                
                                }
                                
                                if ( $mediaquery == true ) {
                                        $newcssstring .= ' } ';
                                    }
                                
                                }

                                $newcssstring .= '</style>';

                            }

                            // Delete old css
                            $message = preg_replace("/<style\\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/style>/s", "<!-- style extracted -->", $message);

                            // Make new body
                            $message = $newcssstring . $message;

                        }
```

Comment: Great job working it out

Answer (score -1):

The code have some error, anyway the simpliest way is to use the [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) php function

```
$newstring=str_replace("{",".mydiv {",$string);
```

Comment: That would end up with classes like `body .mydiv { blah blah } .div1 .mydiv { blah blah }`, not `body { blah blah } .mydiv .div1 { blah blah }`