# PHP CSS Parser - Selector Declarations to String

Tags: php, css, parsing, css-parsing

I want to be able to read a CSS file, and be able to extract all declarations of a given selector in to a string. For example, given the following stylesheet:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div.item {
  font-size: 12px;
  border:1px solid #EEE;
}
```

I want to be able to call and get div.item, something like:

```
$css->getSelector('div.item');
```

Which should give me a string like:

```
font-size:12px;border:1px solid #EEE;
```

I have been looking around but can't find a parser that can do exactly that. Any ideas?

FYI: I need this to be able to convert selectors from a CSS and embed the styles dynamically in to HTML elements in email messages.

**SOLUTION**
EDIT: I came up with my own crude solution and created a class to do what I was looking for. See my own answer below.

Comment: Googling for "php css parser" gave me this as the first hit: https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

Comment: Yes, looked at that. It can't do individual selectors... that's in his todo list.

Comment: very nice solution you should put that as the answer

Comment: Thanks. Apparently I have to wait for 8 hours... so I just edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with my own crude solution and created a class to do what I was looking for. My sources are referenced at the bottom.

```
class css2string {
    var $css;

    function parseStr($string) {
        preg_match_all( '/(?ims)([a-z0-9, \s\.\:#_\-@]+)\{([^\}]*)\}/', $string, $arr);
        $this->css = array();
        foreach ($arr[0] as $i => $x)
        {
            $selector = trim($arr[1][$i]);
            $rules = explode(';', trim($arr[2][$i]));
            $this->css[$selector] = array();
            foreach ($rules as $strRule)
            {
                if (!empty($strRule))
                {
                    $rule = explode(":", $strRule);
                    $this->css[$selector][trim($rule[0])] = trim($rule[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function arrayImplode($glue,$separator,$array) {
        if (!is_array($array)) return $array;
        $styleString = array();
        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            if (is_array($val))
                $val = implode(',',$val);
            $styleString[] = "{$key}{$glue}{$val}";

        }
        return implode($separator,$styleString);   
    }

    function getSelector($selectorName) {
        return $this->arrayImplode(":",";",$this->css[$selectorName]);
    }

}
```

You can run it as follows:

```
$cssString = "
h1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div.item {
  font-size: 12px;
  border:1px solid #EEE;
}";

$getStyle = new css2string();
$getStyle->parseStr(cssString);
echo $getStyle->getSelector("div.item");
```

The output would be as follows:

```
font-size:12px;border:1px solid #EEE
```

This solution works even with comments within your CSS file, as long as the comments are not inside selectors.

References:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php#106085
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215074/break-a-css-file-into-an-array-with-php

Comment: What happens if you have comments in your css? `$cssString = "h1 { /* a } comment*/ }";`

Comment: Well, I built this for myself and I don't expect to have comments in my CSS. Feel free to modify and update it to fulfill your needs.

Comment: Fair enough, just don't be surprised if something breaks all of a sudden when you _do_ decide to comment your code :)

Comment: Thanks... I know it's need another preg_match inside the for loop to discard the comment. But again, don't need to worry about it right now.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

http://classes.verkoyen.eu/css_to_inline_styles

CssToInlineStyles is a class that enables you to convert HTML-pages/files into HTML-pages/files with inline styles. This is very usefull when you're sending emails.
I'm using it right now and works fine.

An example using some methods:

```
$html = file_get_contents('blue.html');
```

// my styles are stored inside the html

```
$cssConverter = new CSSToInlineStyles();
$cssConverter->setCleanup(true);
$cssConverter->setHTML($html);
$cssConverter->convert(true);
$cssConverter->setUseInlineStylesBlock(true);

$new_html = $cssConverter->convert();
```

Comment: Thanks. But I wrote my own class... see my question.