# DOMDocument - how to replace nested elements

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

I've this html fragment:

```
<font color="#ff0000">Lorem <font size="4">ipsum dolor</font> sit amet</font>
```

and i want to replace each `font` tag with a `span`, using DOMDocument.
That's my function atm:

```
$fonts = $xPath->query('//font');
foreach($fonts as $font){
    $style = '';
    $newFont = $dom->createElement('span',$font->nodeValue);
    if($font->hasAttribute('size')){
        $size = $font->getAttribute('size');
        $style.='font-size:'.round($size/2,1).'em; ';
    }
    if($font->hasAttribute('color')){
        $style.='color:'.$font->getAttribute('color').'; ';
    }
    if($style!='') $newFont->setAttribute('style',$style);
    $font->parentNode->replaceChild($newFont,$font);
}
```

I expected this output:

```
<span style="color:#ff0000; ">Lorem <span style="font-size:2em;">ipsum etc..
```

But i get:

```
<span style="color:#ff0000; ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
```

Why?

---

I guess it happens because `$font->parentNode->replaceChild($newFont,$font);` is somehow replacing the outer span with just its text value... Or maybe this query `$xPath->query('//font')` is wrong.  I'ld love an experienced suggestion... thanks

Comment: Why don't you simply use regular expressions?

Comment: @rekire i've been doing that for a long time, but i'm trying to switch to DOMDocument / html5lib ... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: I know that html tag pairs cannot be replaced with regular expressions, but that simple closing font tags can been replaced with an closing span in every case isn't it?

Comment: yup @rekire i could handle this particular case even with str_replace and preg_match... i just want to understand how DOMDocument works, but i get lost in the official documentation ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Introduction

From the following conversations

rekire

> Why don't you simply use regular expressions? –

GionaF

> rekire i've been doing that for a long time, but i'm trying to switch to DOMDocument / html5lib ... codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html`

I totally agree that is why i believe this is not a Job for Both `DomDocument` & `Regular Expresstion` because you are dealing with issues of `depreciated HTML Tags` that are no longer supported in HTML 5

### Implication

This means that `font` is not your only issue you might also have to replace

- acronym
- applet
- basefont
- big
- center
- dir
- frame
- frameset
- noframes
- s
- strike
- tt
- xmp

### Use Tidy

I would Recommend [Tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.tidy.php) which was designed so that you don't have to do what you are about to do

**FORM PHP DOC**

> Tidy is a binding for the Tidy HTML **clean** and **repair** utility which allows you to not only clean and otherwise manipulate HTML documents, **but also traverse the document tree**.

### Example

```
$html = '<font color="#ff0000">Lorem <font size="4">ipsum dolor</font> sit amet</font>';
$config = array(
        'indent' => true,
        'show-body-only' => false,
        'clean' => true,
        'output-xhtml' => true,
        'preserve-entities' => true);

$tidy = new tidy();
echo $tidy->repairString($html, $config, 'UTF8');
```

Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            /*<![CDATA[*/
            span.c2 {
                color: #FF0000
            }
            span.c1 {
                font-size: 120%
            }
            /*]]>*/
        </style>
    </head>
    <body><span class="c2">Lorem <span class="c1">ipsum dolor</span> sit amet</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

See also see [Cleaning HTML by removing extra/redundant formatting tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248166/cleaning-html-by-removing-extra-redundant-formatting-tags/10308209#10308209) for examples

### Better Sill : HTMLPurifier

You can use **[HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)** which also uses Tidy to clean up the HTML all you need is to set the TidyLevel

HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant HTML filter library written in PHP. HTML Purifier will not only **remove all malicious code** (better known as XSS) with a thoroughly audited, secure yet permissive whitelist, it will also make sure your **documents are standards compliant**, something only achievable with a comprehensive knowledge of W3C's specifications

```
require_once 'htmlpurifier-4.4.0/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$html = '<font color="#ff0000">Lorem <font size="4">ipsum dolor</font> sit amet</font>';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.TidyLevel', 'heavy'); 
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$clean = $purifier->purify($html);

var_dump($clean);
```

Output

```
string '<span style="color:#ff0000;">Lorem <span style="font-size:large;">ipsum dolor</span> sit amet</span>' (length=100)
```

### I want DOMDocument

If all you want is dom and you don't care about all my explanations then you can use

```
$html = '<font color="#ff0000">Lorem <font size="4">ipsum dolor</font> sit amet</font>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = iterator_to_array($dom->getElementsByTagName('font'));
foreach ( $nodes as $font ) {
    $css = array();
    $font->hasAttribute('size') and $css[] = 'font-size:' . round($font->getAttribute('size') / 2, 1) . 'em;';
    $font->hasAttribute('color') and $css[]  = 'color:' . $font->getAttribute('color') . ';';
    $span = $dom->createElement('span');
    $children = array();
    foreach ( $font->childNodes as $child )
        $children[] = $child;
    foreach ( $children as $child )
        $span->appendChild($child);
    $span->setAttribute('style', implode('; ', $css));
    $font->parentNode->replaceChild($span, $font);
}
echo "<pre>";
$dom->formatOutput = true;
print(htmlentities($dom->saveXML()));
```

Comment: Both your HTMLPurifier and DOMDocument methods work like a charm! Again, thanks a lot. I've just a small issue left: how can i produce an html5 output? HTMLPurifier will turn a `<br>` into `<br/>`. So at the moment i'm passing the formatted `$clean` to [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/): `HTML5_Parser::parse($clean)`. Is there a way to achieve the same result with HTMLPurifier only?

Comment: `HTMLPurifier` actually uses tidy to achieve this ... `<br />` for now it only tidy i am certain has the feature

Comment: Mmmh i see. Sad that fantastic libraries like DOMDocument and Querypath doesn't support html5 yet. Thanks for your time Baba, i owe you one ;-)

Comment: You are welcome anytime ...looking at https://wiki.php.net/rfc am not sure HTML would be supported anytime soon

Comment: Why are you using iterartor_to_array function here to convert the DOMNodeList object?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with XSL to change the tags to spans.

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadXML('<font color="#ff0000">Lorem <font size="4">ipsum dolor</font> sit amet</font>');

echo "Starting Point:" . $dom->saveXML() . PHP_EOL;

$xsl = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
// Could be a seperate file
$xsl->loadXML(<<<XSLT
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

    <!-- Identity rule -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="."/></xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="font">
        <xsl:element name="span">
            <xsl:attribute name="style" xsl:space="default">
                <xsl:if test="@size">font-size: <xsl:value-of select="round(@size * 10 div 2) div 10" /> em;</xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="@color">color: <xsl:value-of select="@color" />;</xsl:if>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
XSLT
);

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStylesheet($xsl);
echo $proc->transformToXML($dom);
```

Comment: +1 for using your time to write this answer ... doesn't work in my own case because i don't have control over the markup, but it could be useful to someone else

Comment: Very cool! Would it be possible to change this so that comments are correctly indented and CDATA sections are NOT added and HTML5 self-closing tags don't come out as inline empty tags such as `<br></br>`?

Comment: There are a number of options in xslt to fiddle with that can tweak the output.  On: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt there is <xsl:preserve-space/>, and <xsl:output method=""/> that may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It appear your code sample is running into a couple of different issues.

1. The query results contain items that are changing
2. $node->nodValue doesn't contain the child nodes

Found changing from a foreach to a while, and running the query multiple times got around the issue with finding nodes in a changing tree.

```
$fonts = $xPath->query('//font');
while ($fonts->length > 0) {
    $font = $fonts->item(0);

    // Get bits of data before touching the tree

    $style   = '';
    if($font->hasAttribute('size')){
        $size   = $font->getAttribute('size');
        $style .= 'font-size:' . round($size/2, 1) . 'em; ';
    }
    if($font->hasAttribute('color')){
        $style .= 'color:' . $font->getAttribute('color') . '; ';
    }

    // Create the new node

    $newFont = $dom->createElement('span');
    if(!empty($style)) {
        $newFont->setAttribute('style', $style);
    }


    // Copy all children into a basic array to avoid an iterator
    // on a changing tree
    $children = iterator_to_array($font->childNodes);
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        // This has a side effect of removing the child from its old
        // location, which changes the tree
        $newFont->appendChild($child);
    }

    // Replace the parent's child, which changes the tree
    $font->parentNode->replaceChild($newFont, $font);


    // query again on the new tree
    $fonts = $xPath->query('//font');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! So there's no easy way for replacing nested elements with DOMDocument?