# How to trim html tag and format using php?

Tags: php, html, tags

For Example

```
$string = '<i>Line1</i><i><i><i><i><i></i></i></i></i></i><i><i><i><i>
              <i>Line 2</i></i></i></i></i><i><i><i><i><i></i></i></i></i>
              </i><i><i><i><i><i>Line 3</i></i></i></i></i>';
```

How do I remove the tag if the content inside of it is Empty and how do I close the tag if it's not closed 
using php

> < / i >

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: You do realize that all those tags have content inside them right?

Comment: yes, can u please help...

Answer (score 4):

You can use `strip_tags` for this

```
$string ='<i>Line1</i><i><i><i><i><i></i></i></i></i></i><i><i><i><i>
          <i>Line 2</i></i></i></i></i><i><i><i><i><i></i></i></i></i>
          </i><i><i><i><i><i>Line 3</i></i></i></i></i>';
```

To strip the tags

```
echo strip_tags($string);
```

One way through for formatting tags that are not closed is

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string);
$string = $doc->saveHTML();
```

We can also use regex to remove empty html tags. Here's a small function to do it.

```
function remove_empty_tags ($string, $rep = NULL)
{
   if (!is_string ($string)
      || trim ($string) == '')
          return $string;

   return preg_replace ('/<([^<\/>]*)>([\s]*?|(?R))<\/\1>/imsU',!is_string ($rep) ? '' : $rep,$string);
}

$string = remove_empty_tags($string);
```

Comment: Won't this remove all tags, and not just the ones with no content. Also, this won't close the unclosed tags.

Comment: Yes your are right. To remove tags that have no content we can use Regex.

Comment: @Sean I have updated my answer, in which i have written a function to remove empty html tags using Regex.

Comment: Well @ShameemAhmed. Actually one problem. For Example <i><i>Test</i></i>. Actually i need <i>Test</i>. Please help me ..

Comment: For that i would recommend you to go through regex, you can do it using regex with some trail and errors. Otherwise you can go through this post   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248166/cleaning-html-by-removing-extra-redundant-formatting-tags