# How do I replace dots/hashtags and spaces on this css parse function?

Tags: php, regex

I am taking a CSS file and breaking it down into an array so I can use the data for another purpose. I found a function that does exactly what I need here ( I don't need a fancy CSS Parser as my styles are very basic in form, and this functions works well: [Break a CSS file into an array with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215074/break-a-css-file-into-an-array-with-php)

```
<?php

$css = <<<CSS
#selector { display:block; width:100px; }
#selector a { float:left; text-decoration:none }
.wrapper ul {font-size:20px}
CSS;

//
function BreakCSS($css)
{

    $results = array();

    preg_match_all('/(.+?)\s?\{\s?(.+?)\s?\}/', $css, $matches);
    foreach($matches[0] AS $i=>$original)
        foreach(explode(';', $matches[2][$i]) AS $attr)
            if (strlen(trim($attr)) > 0) // for missing semicolon on last element, which is legal
            {
                list($name, $value) = explode(':', $attr);
                $results[$matches[1][$i]][trim($name)] = trim($value);
            }
    return $results;
}
var_dump(BreakCSS($css));
```

However, I need to figure out an additional piece. I would like the CSS selectors' #(ids), .(classes) and spaces removed in the final array. For example '#selector a' becomes 'selector-a' and '.wrapper ul' becomes 'wrapper-ul'. I am new, but I think preg_replace would handle that. But I am just unsure on how to integrate that into my match that then gets fed into foreach loop. Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: `[#.]` will match either of the characters `#` or `.`. Does that point you in the right direction? Any more would just write the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else reading this (apart from OP), I would not suggest using this method. Since the OP has a very specific use-case and is only looking to extend the current method he's using, the following can be used:

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##VVJdb@MgEHwuv2KlWjLWNXHaRzttdHc/IY@uFXF4HaNiQICb9CL/9hzY13ysLKSFmdlhjOnM@bzemM4QknDn4BXW6/Xv7ZY8OpTIvbZwgkY4I9lX8Udq/lHCQTS@K55XK3MsYbxBsoBtpWa@kNj6Ejwe/aJBri3zQqtCaYWBsDxYZgxaGCScWq38wom/WLwEvZGE2SUheU7aQfHIgl8W2UfYptFgRk6EQKjEohukj46ZteyLZuV8YCzudz3zvNsxKWma0@WPTfbuNu@nsFyaMU@fICqGdUKjCwpRoNVhIO/o93a1quHnFhLx@pZoK/ZCMZlNyFs0Ho3UDdK0TK@K1UtdJaLOJj7z3l55sUQL1HkrUVFvRU9nSAZvsMogz6M29MI5ofbgsBdcy5BH@CRzHkLqPSr/BIdO8A6EA4l7Ju8mnO66WFI4TxPFegw2P5kcMAsRXtwX0f1koyQPD4kKZ1OgFsML4AGQV4/LOmaX3t7zeb7nhRNudaVARC8iXP2P@La@f2SVqLqaY4jusjrIzO3s8p45Tp1FP1h1kSjJSD6Z3TVDb@j9s8nK8/kf)

```
<?php

$css = <<<CSS
#selector { display:block; width:100px; }
#selector a { float:left; text-decoration:none }
.wrapper ul {font-size:20px}
CSS;

//
function BreakCSS($css)
{

    $results = array();

    preg_match_all('/(.+?)\s?\{\s?(.+?)\s?\}/', $css, $matches);
    foreach($matches[0] AS $i=>$original)
        foreach(explode(';', $matches[2][$i]) AS $attr)
            if (strlen(trim($attr)) > 0) // for missing semicolon on last element, which is legal
            {
                list($name, $value) = explode(':', $attr);
                $n = preg_replace('/[#.]/', '', $matches[1][$i]);
                $n = str_replace(' ', '-', $n);
                $results[$n][trim($name)] = trim($value);
            }
    return $results;
}
var_dump(BreakCSS($css));
```

The modification:

```
$n = preg_replace('/[#.]/', '', $matches[1][$i]);    // added line
$n = str_replace(' ', '-', $n);                      // added line
$results[$n][trim($name)] = trim($value);            // edited line
```

The first line above replaces `#` and `.` in the selector with no character.
The second line above replaces the spaces in the selector with `-`.

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  ["selector"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["display"]=>
    string(5) "block"
    ["width"]=>
    string(5) "100px"
  }
  ["selector-a"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["float"]=>
    string(4) "left"
    ["text-decoration"]=>
    string(4) "none"
  }
  ["wrapper-ul"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["font-size"]=>
    string(4) "20px"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. yes very helpful for just my exact need